# USB Solution to Bit Bang RS485 at a high Baud Rate

Tags: usb, serial, rs485

I am searching for a solution to write a ~800 byte data stream at a 10K baud rate from a USB device.

This is going to connect to a piece of hardware that uses a RS485 connection which expects an unconventional data stream (which is why I needed to use a bit bang mode).

I was using a FT232R USB cable to attempt to do this. The only problem is I need to write in a byte at a time to the chip, and I have to deal with the delay of the Windows USB Scheduler.. which seems to be around a ~1ms.
So in order to keep up, I need to write a new bit every 100 microseconds (10K Baud Rate). So at my needed rate, I simply wouldn't be able to keep up. Since the chip can only store a bit output at a time, writing in would take much too long.

Does anyone have any other products they would recommend? I was searching for a solution that would have a buffer, that perhaps I could write a chunk of my data stream (if not all of it) and would allow the datastream to keep up with the 10K baud rate.

The Protocol I need to keep up with is at 10K Baudrate:
Start Bit, 8 Bits of Address, 8 Bits Of Data, 1 Parity Bit, 40 0 Bits, and then repeating to the next 'packet'.

Comment: How "unconventional" is it? Please describe the protocol. We do not recommend products, BTW.

Comment: A straight-forward solution is to use an inexpensive MCU with USB support. Of course, it requires firmware for the MCU and flashing the MCU in production. Is that an option?

Comment: Why a byte at a time? Why can't you write the whole buffer?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Sorry about that. I just edited my post to include a description of the protocol at the bottom. I couldn't find anything like this protocol out there.. which is why I was bit banging the output

Comment: @Justme I am only interfaced to the D0 pin on the FT232RQ, from talking to their support that bit bang mode does not support buffers.. therefore it bottle necks

Comment: @Codo I'm not super familiar with MCUs. I'd probably like to avoid having to write firmware for it. I've been hoping their is a solution which simply has a small buffer that I could fill with my byte stream and support the baud rate

Comment: Microcontroller seem to be the most straightforward and affordable solution. Otherwise it looks like you will need some special pieces of hardware for arbitrary waveform generation - which could be quite expensive.

Comment: So the FTDI bitbang manual that says you can write a whole buffer is wrong?

Comment: Part "shopping" questions are off topic, and doubly so when lacking specifics of the need.   Custom MCU firmware is going to be the most robust, but you might be able to do something by finding a pre-written firmware for one of the USB-based logic analyzers that could allow it to operate in reverse as a signal generator, and feed it a data stream from something like a python program on a PC.

Comment: @Codo I would say USB support programming on the MCU is not even necessary, moreover programming it (USB) without experience might turn a real headache. One can use a conventional UART on the micro to communicate to the host.

Comment: @EugeneSh good to know.. one of the FTDI reps seems to be recommending that as well.

Comment: @Justme for the specific chip it only seems to be support a byte at a time. I think other chips support larger buffers

Comment: If you are using a standard cable from FTDI, change to another similar standard FTDI cable with chip that can support bitbang properly?

Comment: Wrap that ‘unconventional’ bit-bang real-time weirdness with another microcontroller with a serial port.